# Is there a canonical Git logo?

Tags: git

Is there a canonical logo for Git itself, as opposed to GitHub?

Comment: A suggestion: if the first Google hit for "Git logo" answers your question, you probably don't need to ask it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official site has [Git logos](http://git-scm.com/downloads/logos) in various formats.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find it here [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a git only website: http://git-scm.com/